# Which page should I redirect to after item edit/creation?

Tags: website-design, usability, mobile, ios, user-expectation

Let's suppose a mobile app aiming to show "all" items, "my" items, and create some items.

The important thing is that an item I create should appear to both "All" and "My".

When I click on "AllItems" tab:

[image]

When I click on "MyItems" tab (note the repeated "My Item One"):

[image]

When I click on "Create", in order to create an item:

[image]

Where should I redirect the user after the creation? 
The main interest of creating an item is to make it public to any users.

Edit is also concerned in the OP since any show/detail page can contain an "edit" button aiming to update "my" item.

Comment: How many items might be there in all items

Comment: Could be one million ;) (paginated or scroll infinite). Logically, as stackexchange does, the targeted page may be the show/detail page, but I'm not sure it's the best way to assert (in user perspective) immediately that the item is visible publicly. Indeed, I don't have a real-time "view counter" yet that can indicate on the show page that the item is currently being viewed. On the other hand, the show page allows to check the correctness of the set item's elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to **put it in My Items** since going by your answer to my question, there will be a lot of items in All Items and it would be easier for the user to find the item he just created in myitems.

Also it would be consistent with experience created by similar apps where you can save content from a huge list and while that content might be still part of the major list, it would part of your curated list as well and easier to find.

Here is how prismatic (a content delivery app I use regularly does it)

### Home View

[image]

### Saved View

[image]

I would also **recommend highlighting the recently saved content with a different color or shading so that it stands out making it easier for someone to find it**.

---

Going by what you asked about the show option, I **would then change my answer to redirect the user to the internal show page which shows the item** he has just created as that would enable him to quickly evaluate the content and make any changes if needed. However I would also recommend that you provide an option to allow him to go to the My items page from there since the My items section is a personalized experience which is exclusive to him.

Comment: So, should I avoid to redirect to the show page ? Show page being internal to My Items for instance.

Comment: Ok a new addition to  your question since I didnt see the show option in the question you had originally written, just see my updated answer for my reference.

Comment: Thanks for the update :)  "I would also recommend that you provide an option to allow him to go to the My items page" => Isn't it enough to expect the user to click on the "My Items" tab?

Comment: Make it easier for him. I would suggest two buttons "edit" and "My items" which would provide two call to actions about his potential next steps.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect to the **detail page** of the item which the user just created/edited.

This allows users to immediately check the result of their submission (they can spot spelling mistakes, syntax/formatting problems, etc.).

To make them aware that the item is published automatically, show a (temporary) message at the top of the detail page, like *Created and published "My Item One"*. You could link "published" to the AllItems or MyItems view, or maybe add a second sentence with link(s): *See your item in the list of all/your items.*.

If there is also the option not to publish an item, it might make more sense to permanently show the publication status on the item’s detail page (only visible to the author): *Published* / *Not published*. If you place this near the top, there would be no need for a success message.